# Centered div all the time

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```css
.center_position_div{
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.show_running_exam
{
    width: 22%;
    background-color:aliceblue;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="center_position_div">
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>


    </div>
```

How can I center divs on the middle parent div? I assume that in the parent div can exist many divs. I could use "padding-left" in parent div, but this is not a universal solution. I tried use "marging: 0 auto;" - still not working. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking to set the content justification. Applying `justify-content: center;` to the parent container should do the trick.

```css
.center_position_div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.show_running_exam {
  width: 22%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="center_position_div">
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
  <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Ohh thanks! Its working. I'm going to remember there is exist something like   justify-content.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```css
.center_position_div{
        width:100%;
        background-color:green;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .show_running_exam
    {
        width: 22%;
        background-color:aliceblue;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-top: 6px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div class="center_position_div">
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>
        <div class="show_running_exam">saddsdsadsdsdf dsfsdfd sfdsfdsfsdfd sfdsfsd</div>


    </div>
```

Comment: I've tested this solution, but not working. But I deleted flex-direction: column; and this gives me a good result.